# Calculate sidebar height without specifying it

Tags: html, css

I have a web app where the layout is created as follows:

- Toolbar
- Sidebar

  - Sidebar head
  - Sidebar body
- Content

Currently is set up like this:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#overlay {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: gray;
}

#toolbar {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#sidebar-head {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar-body {
  height: calc(100vh - 144px);
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="toolbar">
      <p>Toolbar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="sidebar-head">
        <p>Sidebar Head</p>
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar-body">
        <ul>
          <li>Sidebar Body</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My question is: is it possible to somehow set up the layout without specifying the height of the sidebar body like `height: calc(100vh - 144px);`. I'm asking this because in my app the toolbar has a lot of items, so when the user has a smaller screen, the toolbar changes its height, and the calculation `height: calc(100vh - 144px);` becomes irrelevant, because the height is changed. Obviously, I can set up a different height for every breakpoint where the toolbar height changes, but I really want to avoid that route if possible.

Comment: have you tried height: 100%;?

Comment: you can calculate height using jquery

Comment: you may calculate height like that way may be `let sidebar_body = document.getElementById('sidebar-body');
console.log(sidebar_body.offsetHeight)`

Comment: I don't really understand what you want the end product to look like.
Your #toolbar and #sidebar-head won't change heights even if screen sizes is smaller so the calc function seems right to me.

Comment: @HerrKingsley they didn't change in this example. But in my real app they do change.

Comment: remove that height and add `min-height: 0;` to #sidebar

Comment: @TemaniAfif what kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: check the duplicate to get more details

Comment: How is this a duplicate? Totally different things.